# How To include files remotely and access the variables

Tags: php

I have file at some server... file is 
www.iamtushar.com/file/index.php

```
<?PHP
$var=2;
?>
```

Now i want to include this file and use the value of the variable $var on some other server..

Suppose the other script is www.howtodothis.com/index.php and i want to use $var of the above file here....

```
<?php

include('www.iamtushar.com/file/index.php');
echo $var;

?>
```

but it does not work, however it works if the file is on the same server and same browser..

please help...

Comment: in short, you cant. file is served via the web server and the php run server side, you just get the output. Not a good idea for speed regardless.

Comment: The reason JS works is because it's client side while PHP is server side.

Comment: I'm afraid @Dagon is right, this way you can't. Only way to make this work is to mount the source from the other server using NFS or SSHFS or comparable, making it available on your server.

Comment: It isn't supposed to work, if it would, that would be a **TREMENDOUS** security hole. You could get the output of the file though, so you could just echo the $var value in the external file, and then get the output with php, probably with file_get_contents()

Comment: this would only work if the remote server doesn't know how to handle .php and simply returns the source contents :)

Answer (score 1):

It does not work since PHP can only output yout `$var` to client. Making this, I believe, is possible if you output content of your `index.php` file to client and then your other `index.php` file gets it and than compiles it on the fly. However it's very bad idea for security/speed reasons.

Your best bet is to output `$var` to browser. Than your other script will take that `2` and place it in your other `$var`.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from security concern, If "URL fopen wrappers" are enabled in PHP (which they are in the default configuration), you can specify the file to be included using a URL (via HTTP or other supported wrapper) :
`include 'http://www.iamtushar.com/file/index.php';`

Comment: how to check URL fopen wrappers open or not ?

Comment: Try dump/outputing `ini_get('allow_url_fopen')` and `ini_get('allow_url_include')`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `include` keyword, use the `require` keyword. Simply replace like this

```
require('www.iamtushar.com/file/index.php');
echo $var;
```

Even better, if you wish to save processing time, just use the `require_once` keyword as so. This way, you ensure that in 1 page load, you only load this PHP file once. Also, it prevents confusion between variables of the same name in different files. You can do so using

```
require_once('www.iamtushar.com/file/index.php');
echo $var;
```